# Google Maps API + Dynamic Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I am trying to create an webpage(web application), for a racing event.

I already have a .kml file which has the way-points and track stored init.
I need to make markers for the teams.

On the map there are way points, so whenever any team reaches a way point, the team marker should be updated to that way-point. Usually this is going to be done by one person, who can click or enter the location and the team marker updates.

I am not sure where should i start. I looked into google Maps API and Javascript, but then again not sure if i can do the updation on markers(make it more semi-dynamic). Would appreciate if you can suggest a simple way of doing this. Would also like to know how can i load my .kml file to the google maps api ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't really want to get into the Maps API (I would recommend being competent with javaScript first).
If you have a google/gmail login what I would recommend trying (at least to see if it fits your needs) is go to http://maps.google.com/
Click on "My Places" in the left window pane.
Click "Create Map".
Click "Import" and upload your kml file.
Then you can just add placemarks (top left area of the map) for each team. 
Click "Collaborate" to allow others with google accounts to modify the map.
Click Done whenever finished with your edits.
If you want to send the map to someone (read-only) there is a "KML" link to export it with the placemarks.

Note, none of this will be automated, someone will have to log in and edit the team positions each time they reach a checkpoint. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i wanted to post this as a webpage, where everyone can see this during the race. Moreover the user would need to updated it, isn't it possible i can create something, which will update the map when the change happens ?